# Reshape a matrix by splitting it after k columns in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose that I have a matrix , let's call it A, as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9
```

And I want to reshape it into a matrix like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
0 2 4 6 8
1 2 3 4 5
1 3 5 7 9
```

So, basically, what I want to be done is that MATLAB first reads a block of size (2,5) and then splits the remaining matrix to the next row and then repeats this  so on so forth until we get something like in my example.

I tried to do this using MATLAB's reshape command in several ways but I failed. Any help is appreciated. In case that it matters, my original data is larger. It's (2,1080). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this in a single command, but perhaps someone will correct me. If speed isn't a huge concern a for loop should work fine.

Alternatively you can get your results by reshaping each row of A and then placing the results into every other row of a new matrix. This will also work with your larger data.

```
A = [1     2     3     4     5     1     2     3     4     5
     0     2     4     6     8     1     3     5     7     9];
An = zeros(numel(A)/5, 5);               % Set up new, empty matrix
An(1:2:end,:) = reshape(A(1,:), 5, [])'; % Write the first row of A to every other row of An
An(2:2:end,:) = reshape(A(2,:), 5, [])'  % Write second row of A to remaining rows
```

An =

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 0     2     4     6     8
 1     2     3     4     5
 1     3     5     7     9
```

Comment: Thanks. What does An(1:2:end,:) mean? I had never seen : used twice in the same argument. Could you explain it please?

Comment: In colon notation the second value is the step size, for example `1:0.5:10` will give a set of values in 0.5 increments (`[1, 1.5, 2, ..., 10]`). `An(1:2:end)` will access every other row, starting from the first row, in the `An` matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to read more about indexing in the Matlab's documentation.

For your example, it is easy to do the following

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5; 0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9]
a1=A(:,1:5); % extract all rows, and columns from 1 to 5
a2=A(:,6:end); % extract all rows, and columns from 6 to end 
B=[a1;a2] % construct a new matrix.
```

It is not difficult to build some sort of loops to extract the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can do it in one line using the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) commands:

```
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A,2,5,[]), [1,3,2]), [], 5);
```

The `reshape(A,2,5,[])` command reshapes your A matrix into a three-dimensional tensor of dimension `2 x 5 x nblocks`, where `nblocks` is the number of blocks in A in the horizontal direction. The `permute` command then swaps the 2nd and 3rd dimensions of this 3D tensor, so that it becomes a `2 x nblocks x 5` tensor. The final `reshape` command then transforms the 3D tensor into a matrix of dimension `(2*nblocks) x 5`.

Looking at the results at each stage may give you a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Could you explain what your answer does?